Applying global autodocs in Storybook not working
I have a Storybook design system and I would like to generate autodocs. The  documentation says it should by done like this in preview.ts :
const preview: Preview = {
  parameters: {
    actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
    viewport: {
      viewports: { ...customViewports }
    },
    docs: {
      theme: create({
        base: 'light',
        fontBase: '"Open Sans", sans-serif'
      })
    }
  },
  tags: ['autodocs']
}

However, it is not working for me, No docs file is generated for each of my stories. The interesting thing is, when I apply it to a specific component in the Meta part, it works for this specific component:
const meta: Meta = {
  title: 'CustomComponent',
  component: 'CustomComponent',
  argTypes: {
    label: { control: 'text' },
    color: { control: 'color' },
    size: { control: 'number' },
    empty: { control: 'boolean' },
  },
  tags: ['autodocs']
}

But I would like to apply it globally, to all stories, not to add it manually for each of them.
My package.json devDependencies:
{
  "devDependecies":{
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "^8.0.6",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^8.0.6",
  }
...,
}

Does anyone have any suggestions how to fix it?
